# Compile .c file (with gcc) and run it taking inputs from file

Tags: gcc, cmd, exec

I'm creating a web site(php) to compile .c files and run the .exe file with some inputs which is located in a file. My opeation system is windows. I'm uploading the .c file and then i excute the exec(gcc...) command. Could you tell the way how that uploaded file could compile(if is other better way), run with some inputs and take back the results?

Comment: why was this tagged with `php`?

Comment: all the above things finally i need to excute it from php

Comment: Why run that from PHP? How precisely would you do that? Why not code everything in PHP, or use some HTTP server library (e.g. [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion/)...) from your C code? Mixing several programming languages is overkill in your case. If PHP is required, read about [extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.structure.php) in PHP if you want to call your C code from PHP.

Comment: Coud you tell me the best way for my project please  . I have a web page, and i upload .c file. after that i need to compile that .c file, run it with some inputs (located somewhere) and take the rerults

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52346047/edit) your question to improve it (smells like some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)..). Give more context. What problem do you want to solve. Don't comment your own question, but add several paragraphs in it. Explain on what operating system your web service is running (it often would be Linux). Running arbitrary C code on a web server is a huge security hole

Comment: is now ok after editing?

Comment: My main advice: avoid risking jail. So don't do that.

Comment: it just a project for me but i need to solve it

Comment: A site that appears to do this is https://tio.run/#. I hope you are planning for adequate security against malicious actors.

Comment: How much time can you afford spending on this? Given your apparent lack of knowledge, it could take you as much as a year, and probably more.

Comment: Your question is unclear,  and could illustrate a lack of knowledge of basic web technologies. Could you please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52346047/edit) your question. You'll need to add several paragraphs in it. Explain in your question what you have told in comments. And most importantly, explain the overall goal and motivation: your question smells *badly* like some [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and I guess you don't really need to compile any C code and could achieve your (unstated) goals and needs otherwise. Explain the motivations and goals of your entire project.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [redirection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)) (in your `cmd` window) when running `yourprog.exe`. So if your data is inside `mydata.txt` you would run `yourprog.exe < mydata.txt` in the command line.

You could use [file I/O](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io) (e.g. call `fopen`) when your `main` has more than one argument (e.g. when you run `yourprog.exe mydata.txt`). Then you'll test when the `argc` passed to your `main` is >1 and in such case do `FILE*f = fopen(argv[1], "r");` and read your input (using `fscanf`) from that `f` (after having checked that `f` is not null).

Be sure to read the documentation (e.g. of every function that you use) before coding. Don't forget to enable all warnings and debug info (so compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g yourprog.c -o yourprog.exe`... improve your code to get no warnings).

Of course read [*How To Debug Small Programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

> I'm creating a web site to compile .c files and run the .exe file with some inputs

You probably don't have the skills to do that wisely (there are huge security risks involved); if you did, you won't have asked your question in such vague terms. Why don't you use [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/) ?

If you still want to compile and run arbitrary C code on a publicly accessible web server, you first should think about avoiding [vulnerabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulnerability_(computing)) (you don't want to go to jail if some bad guy on a different continent uploaded malicious C code and run it on *your* server, and you'll probably be accountable and legally responsible when that happens). Read about [containerization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating-system-level_virtualization) and be aware that most solutions (they are difficult to understand) are above Linux (so you need to learn Linux first)

You might also consider translating the C code to [Webassembly](https://webassembly.org/) (or perhaps Javascript) and run the result on the user's browser. That won't be easy, but alleviate risks on the web server (since the C code would run in the client browser).

If you just want to develop an internal site (only accessible on some intranet from people you trust) you could consider using PHP's [popen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.popen.php) function (to run some `gcc.exe` command, or to run `yourprog.exe`, and take care of its output). That PHP function is inspired by POSIX [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) (for which you'll find tons of examples and explanations).

You may lack basic knowledge about operating systems. You could read [*Operating Systems: Three Easy Pieces*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/) to get them. Be sure to also understand more the [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP) protocol and HTML5 and related technologies (AJAX, Websockets, etc...). You could lack knowledge about them too!

I also tend to believe that Linux (which is used on most web servers, BTW) is much more friendly for your goals than Windows. But your goals are much more ambitious and difficult than what you believe.

Comment: the site could be used only from specific people not from everyone. i want to excute simple projects. there is no risk from malicious code

Comment: Dear Basile Starynkevitch, could you please explaine more the "php's popen function and how i could run an .exe file with inputs from a file?

Comment: No, you need to spend many days (or even weeks) to read more. BTW, I don't know PHP and never used it. (I would recommend you to code your website with [ocsigen](http://ocsigen.org/) instead). My feeling is that you lack a lot of programming skills & elementary knowledge to achieve your goals. You have to learn these before (and that could take months)

Comment: So my feeling is that you don't have enough knowledge to achieve your goals. They are much less simple than what they seem. See http://norvig.com/21-days.html for a useful insight

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: from cmd if you want to run a test.exe file with inputs from inputs.txt and save your ouputs in output.txt you just write this.  test.exe < inputs.txt > output.txt